# Error when wrapping the view of a 3rd-party Django app? (Facebook, django-socialregistration, django-profiles)

Tags: django, facebook, view

I'm using **django-socialregistration** to manage my site's connection with Facebook.

When a user clicks the "Connect with Facebook" button, I am able to automatically create a new Django user and log them in. However, I also need to create a UserProfile (my AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE) record for them which contains their Facebook profile information (email, name, location).

I believe I need to override socialregistration's "setup" view so I can do what I need to do with UserProfile. I've added the following to my project's urls.py file:

> url( r'^social/setup/$', 'myapp.views.socialreg.pre_setup', name='socialregistration_setup'),

My custom view is here "/myapp/views/socialreg.py" and looks like:

```
from socialregistration.forms import UserForm

def pre_setup(request, template='socialregistration/setup.html', 
              form_class=UserForm, extra_context=dict()):
    # will add UserProfile storage here...
    return socialregistration.views.setup(request, template, form_class, extra_context)
```

The socialregistration view signature I'm overriding looks like this:

```
def setup(request, template='socialregistration/setup.html',
          form_class=UserForm, extra_context=dict()):
    ...
```

I'm getting the error **"ViewDoesNotExist at /social/setup/: Could not import myapp.views.socialreg. Error was: No module named socialregistration.views"** when I try the solution above.

The socialregistration app is working fine when I don't try to override the view, so it is likely installed correctly in site-packages. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm also exploring using a decorator instead of overriding the app's view based on this SO response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1649351/overriding-django-views-with-decorators

Comment: This looks an awful lot like the other question you asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3982443/how-do-you-wrap-the-view-of-a-3rd-party-django-app . Yet, there is nothing magic about views - if the module isn't found it's not on your python path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, as Tim noted, this particular problem was path related.

Bigger picture, the way to accomplish what I wanted (creating a linked UserProfile when django-socialregistration creates a user) is best done by passing in a custom form into socialregistration's "setup" view, as the author suggested here: http://github.com/flashingpumpkin/django-socialregistration/issues/issue/36/#comment_482137

Intercept the appropriate url in your urls.py file:

```
from myapp.forms import UserForm    
url('^social/setup/$', 'socialregistration.views.setup', 
    { 'form_class': UserForm }, name='socialregistration_setup'),
(r'^social/', include('socialregistration.urls')),
```

You can base your UserForm off socialregistration's own UserForm, adding in code to populate and save the UserProfile.

Comment: Note that this will not work out of the box if you have SOCIALREGISTRATION_GENERATE_USERNAME = True