# How do you wrap the view of a 3rd-party Django app

Tags: python, django

How do you wrap the view of a 3rd-party app (let's call the view to wrap "view2wrap" and the app "3rd_party_app") so you can do some custom things before the app does its thing?

I've set **urls.py** to capture the correct url:

> url( r'^foo/bar/$', view_wrapper, name='my_wrapper'),

I've created my custom **view**:

```
from 3rd_party_app.views import view2wrap

def view_wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # Do some cool custom stuff
    return view2wrap(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

When I try this, I get the error **"No module named 3rd_party_app.views"**. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third party application is not in your python path.

Comment: But it's in my site-packages directory and I only have a problem with it when I try to wrap the view, if I don't it works fine.

Comment: could you be more specific? what is installed where? what is your pythonpath? what happens if you don't try to call the view?

Answer (score 0):

Is the 3rd Party App listed in INSTALLED_APPS in your settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the 3rd party package folder within your project folder. :)

Comment: I actually tried that and it still didn't work! Somehow, someway after so much tinkering it is working now. Unfortunately I don't know which change was the kicker.